# Color Left and Right backgrounds rather that from the Center

Tags: html, css

Now layout look like this

[image]

What I want to achieve is this

[image]

```
<style type="text/css">
        body { color: #4B5E6F; font-size: 11px; line-height: 1.8em; }
        #main-content-wrapper { background: #F6F7F8; border-left: 1px solid #DBDFE2; border-right: 1px solid #DBDFE2; min-height: 400px; }
        #content-left { float: left; width: 150px; min-height: 400px; background: #F6F7F8; }
        #nav-left { list-style-image: none; margin: 0px; }
        #nav-left li { margin: 6px 0px 6px 0px; }
        #nav-left li .nav-parent { font-family: 'open_sans_extraboldregular'; text-transform: uppercase; color: #595F78; line-height: 22px; text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer; letter-spacing: 0px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 7px; font-size: 12px; }
        #nav-left li .nav-sub { font-family: 'open_sansregular'; color: #595F78; line-height: 22px; text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer; letter-spacing: 0px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 5px; font-size: 11px; }
        #content { float: left; border-left: 1px solid #DBDFE2; border-right: 1px solid #DBDFE2; min-height: 500px; width: 550px; padding: 10px; background: white; }
        #content-right { float: left; width: 216px; padding: 10px; background: white; }
        .nav-left-separator { background: url("resources/images/separator_menu.gif") repeat-x; height: 1px; display: block; margin: 0px 2px 0px 2px; }
        .page-header { font-family: 'open_sansbold'; font-size: 16px; color: #8E354C; line-height: 22px; font-weight: normal; border-bottom: 1px solid #E4E7D4; margin-bottom: 15px; margin-top: 15px; }
        ul { list-style-image: url('resources/images/fleche.gif'); margin: 4px 0px 0px 15px; }
        ul li span { font-family: 'open_sansbold'; }
    </style>

 <div id="main-content-wrapper">
            <div id="content-left">
                <ul id="nav-left">
                    <li><a href="" class="nav-parent">Menu</a></li>
                    <li><span class="nav-left-separator"></span></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="nav-parent">Menu</a></li>
                    <li><span class="nav-left-separator"></span></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="nav-parent">Menu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="nav-sub">Lorem</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="nav-sub">Lorem</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="nav-sub">Lorem</a></li>
                    <li><span class="nav-left-separator"></span></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="nav-parent">Menu</a></li>
                    <li><span class="nav-left-separator"></span></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="nav-parent">Menu</a></li>
                    <li><span class="nav-left-separator"></span></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="nav-parent">Menu</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
            <div id="content">
                <div class="page-header">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>                
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
                when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into 
                electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, 
                and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </div>
            <div id="content-right">
                <div class="page-header">Lorem ipsum</div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                <div class="page-header">Lorem ipsum</div>
                <ul>
                    <li><span>Overview</span></li>
                    <li><span>Overview</span></li>
                    <li><span>Overview</span></li>
                    <li><span>Overview</span></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="page-header">Lorem ipsum</div>
                <ul>
                    <li><span>Overview</span></li>
                    <li><span>Overview</span></li>
                    <li><span>Overview</span></li>
                    <li><span>Overview</span></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want the backgrounds of Left and Right to be colored rather than this from the center, if the center content stretches down, then the Left and Right background needs to be colored too, with their color. Are there any suggestions guys? Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this type of functionality you can use **display:table** property.

For example write like this:

```
div{display:table-cell;width:100px;background:red}

.center{
    background:green;
    width:200px;
}
.right{background:yellow;}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/HuxCZ/

Answer (score 1):

Make the content column divs use `height : 100%`. That should probably stretch the wrapper when needed, taking the other columns with it... In theory...

Comment: Tried it before, and no luck :) Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Here is sample plain code. You can alter your css by comparing with this

HTML

```
<div id="container3">
    <div id="container2">
        <div id="container1">
            <div id="col1">
            test

                <!-- Column one end -->
            </div>
            <div id="col2">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..................
                <!-- Column two end -->
            </div>
            <div id="col3">
                <!-- Column three start -->
                dgh

                <!-- Column three end -->
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

​

CSS

```
#container3 {
    clear:left;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:#89ffa2; /* column 3 background colour */
}
#container2 {
    clear:left;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    right:33.333%;
    background:#ffa7a7; /* column 2 background colour */
}
#container1 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    right:33.33%;
    background:#fff689; /* column 1 background colour */
}
#col1 {
    float:left;
    width:29.33%;
    position:relative;
    left:68.67%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#col2 {
    float:left;
    width:29.33%;
    position:relative;
    left:72.67%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#col3 {
    float:left;
    width:29.33%;
    position:relative;
    left:76.67%;
    overflow:hidden;
}​
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/pV44s/1/

Comment: Thanks mate, your solution works too, but I need now a quick solution to implement, so I accepted the answer of Harold

Answer (score 1):

Remove `float:left` and `min-height` from you inner divs and add `display:table-cell;`

http://jsfiddle.net/N8mDD/2/

Hope this will help